# I have two dimensions which are currencies. Can Tableau recognise them as the same type?

Tags: tableau-api

A data source has several columns which are ISO currency codes: USD, ZAR etc. I'd like them all to display in the same colours and share a single display.

Can tableau do this? Is there any alternative to picking my way through each column and setting every colour by hand?

Comment: Yes! you could do this,just drag that column to colors and you could see the change then click on `color` to choose your own color's

Comment: That was my "setting every colour by hand" option. So perhaps your answer is "No, there's no better way"?  If so I can stop searching for a cleverer way. What I'd like to be able to do is say "this column is the same type as that one and the type's called 'currency' "

Comment: Best way is to create a calculated field called [Currency] (or whatever you want to call it) and consolidate the information of all the columns you have in this single one. If you provide a glimpse of your table, we can help you develop the consolidating function

Comment: @Inox: I'm not sure I follow you. Let a (simplified) row be like this:

Comment: (1.0', 'USD', 2.0, 'ZAR', 3.0, 'JPY')

Comment: I don't see how consolidating them ('USD-ZAR-JPY'?) would help. If I make, say, USD green, then I want all graphs using money columns to treat USD as green. So for example a pair of fields (amount & currency unit) meaning say 'pre-tax profit' would be displayed using the same coding as 'Post tax profit'. Setting the colours is bad enough, if I wanted to annotate say 'ZAR' as 'South African Rand' on every money column, it could take a while.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that, as I'm a programmer, I'm used to being able to define data types and make them work consistently - but it's possible Tableau simply doesn't support this. I'm new to Tableau.

Comment: Okay, now I get it (partially at least). The answer is no, you cannot define colors via coding. No the way you want. You need to define all the colors of the field USD (stop calling them columns, by the way) to be green, for instance.
Now for the other information you passed, what do you mean "this column is the same type as that one and the type's called 'currency' "? Give examples.

Comment: Another thing, avoid relationships by proximity, Tableau can mix fields order (and really doesn't care about it). In you example, if 1.0 is in USD just because it's on the left of USD, you'll have trouble. It's better to have the fields USD, ZAR and JPY, and have 1,2,3 values on those fields.
You should not be working with random structured worksheets, you should be working with tables structures like database

Comment: I am using a database. Fields are 'linked' by naming convention in the usual way. Pity you can't define data domains - it would be a nice feature. But then again, too many nice features might make it unusable for non-programmers. Thanks for confirming this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set default colors for any field by right clicking the field and then set any color you like.Anywhere you use this field in color will have the color you chose as default